# Creating application specific stock icons in GTK3

Tags: python, icons, gtk3

I'm trying to create icons in python and GTK3 for AppIndicator3 , which is using stock items.
When using existing stock icons (like indicator-messages everything is fine.
But when I create my own stock icon it is not displayed (I used both svg and png image).
What can be wrong?

I have this code to add icon factory:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
import os

_curr_dir=os.path.split(__file__)[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    icon_factory=Gtk.IconFactory()
    icon_source=Gtk.IconSource()
    f=os.path.join(_curr_dir, 'pics', 'test.svg')
    if not os.path.exists(f):
        raise Exception('Image %s missing'%f)
    icon_source.set_filename(f)
    icon_source.set_size_wildcarded(True)
    icon_set=Gtk.IconSet()
    icon_set.add_source(icon_source)
    icon_factory.add('myapp-icon', icon_set)
    icon_factory.add_default()

    ind = appindicator.Indicator.new (
                          "example-simple-client",
                          "myapp-icon",
                          appindicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)
    ind.set_status (appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    ind.set_attention_icon ("indicator-messages-new")
    ind.set_label("test", "test")
```